# How to Fast MySQL Execute?

Tags: mysql

Hi I am beginner for coding, I am try to execute my query in database but I wait too long (5-7minute the most are 10minute) my result in data are 1,800 rows How to execute to fast?
my Query

```
SELECT
        pn.plant_name,
        dl.devName,
        dds.run_state,
        dds.inverter_state,
        dds.time_save
FROM
        plant_name pn
        LEFT JOIN plant_data pd ON pn.stationcode = pd.stationcode
        LEFT JOIN device_list dl ON pn.stationcode = dl.stationcode
        LEFT JOIN Device_Data_String dds ON dl.deviceid = dds.devIds
        LEFT JOIN inv_status iss ON dds.inverter_state = iss.State_value
WHERE
        dds.date_save = "2023-7-19"
GROUP BY
        pn.plant_name,
        dl.devName,
        dds.run_state,
        dds.inverter_state,
        dds.time_save
```

My result are 1,800rows

and my Entity Relationship Diagram
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psRBL.png)

I try to `EXPLAIN` my query have result here

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+----------------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------+----------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys        | key         | key_len | ref                           | rows  | filtered | Extra                              |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+----------------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------+----------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dds   | NULL       | ALL    | devIds               | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                          | 25818 |    10.00 | Using where; Using temporary       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | iss   | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY     | 4       | proto02_r3.dds.inverter_state |     1 |   100.00 | Using index                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dl    | NULL       | ref    | deviceid,stationcode | deviceid    | 83      | proto02_r3.dds.devIds         |   385 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pn    | NULL       | ref    | stationcode          | stationcode | 403     | proto02_r3.dl.stationcode     |     1 |   100.00 | Using index condition              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pd    | NULL       | ref    | stationcode          | stationcode | 323     | proto02_r3.pn.stationcode     |   371 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index           |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+----------------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+-------+----------+------------------------------------+
5 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

and I edit code to

```
SELECT
    pn.plant_name,
    dl.devName,
    dds.run_state,
    dds.inverter_state,
    dds.time_save
FROM
    Device_Data_String dds
    LEFT JOIN inv_status iss ON dds.inverter_state = iss.State_value
    INNER JOIN device_list dl ON dds.devIds = dl.deviceid
    INNER JOIN plant_name pn ON dl.stationcode = pn.stationcode
    LEFT JOIN plant_data pd ON pn.stationcode = pd.stationcode
WHERE
    dds.date_save = "2023-07-19"
GROUP BY
    pn.plant_name,
    dl.devName,
    dds.run_state,
    dds.inverter_state,
    dds.time_save;
```

but it's not work!, It's use about 6minute(368.96s)
Thank you for see my question and answer to help me very much I hope someone to helpม I really don't know What should I do?

Comment: Try to create index on join columns. It should execute faster then.

Comment: it look like that there is no INDEX on **dds.date_save**

Comment: What's the reason for `LEFT JOIN plant_data pd` when `pd` is not referenced anywhere else in your query? As Bernd suggested - `ALTER TABLE Device_Data_String ADD INDEX idx_date_save (date_save);`

Answer (score 0):

Create an index for Device_Data_String.date_save:

```
create index date_save_ind on Device_Data_String (date_save, devIds)
```

Remove the unused tables from the query and make it more readable by using DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    pn.plant_name,
    dl.devName,
    dds.run_state,
    dds.inverter_state,
    dds.time_save
FROM
    Device_Data_String dds
    INNER JOIN device_list dl ON dds.devIds = dl.deviceid
    INNER JOIN plant_name pn ON dl.stationcode = pn.stationcode
WHERE
    dds.date_save = "2023-07-19"
```